# How to perform LINQ ThenBy in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, grouping

I have simple data:

```
type age 
A    4   
A    4   
B    4   
A    5
```

I want to get

```
type age count
A    4    2
A    5    1
B    4    1
```

How to perform such thing in panda: what shell I do after `df.groupby(['type'])`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use `groupby` with 'type' and 'age', then `count` and `reset_index`:

```
df.groupby(['type','age'])['age'].count().reset_index(name='count')
```

Output:

```
  type  age  count
0    A    4      2
1    A    5      1
2    B    4      1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do

> ```
> df.groupby(['type','age']).size().reset_index(name='count')
> ```

Comment: Can I know why this is down voted when it gives a right answer?