# How to create a Bokeh HeatMap from a table with repeating labels?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visualization, jupyter, bokeh

My data looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45180703/1973207):

```
  type  age  count
0    A    4      2
1    A    5      1
2    B    4      1
```

I want to get a Bokeh HeatMap like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41283104/1973207) out from it. Yet I get

```
C:\Users\panda\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bokeh\charts\stats.py in binstr_to_list(bins)
    197     def binstr_to_list(bins):
    198         """Produce a consistent display of a bin of data."""
--> 199         value_chunks = bins.split(',')
    200         value_chunks = [val.replace('[', '').replace(']', '').replace('(', '').replace(')', '') for val in value_chunks]
    201         bin_values = [float(value) for value in value_chunks]

AttributeError: 'pandas._libs.interval.Interval' object has no attribute 'split'
```

To get it I added to data creation:

```
HeatMap(ages, x='type', y='age', values='count')
```

Answer (score 0):

The `bokeh.charts` API including `HeatMap` was deprecated and removed entirely some time ago. Instead, the stable and supported `bokeh.plotting` API can be used. There are [complete examples of heat maps](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/categorical.html#heat-maps) in the main documentation section on [Handling Categorical Data](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/categorical.html).

Here is a simplifed version of your code:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show

p = figure(x_range=('A', 'B'), plot_height=300)

types = ['A', 'A', 'B']
ages = [4, 5, 4]
colors = ['red', 'blue', 'blue'] # map of age = [2, 1, 1]

p.rect(x=types, y=ages, width=1, height=1, fill_color=colors, line_color="white")

show(p)
```

[image]

For real code you might consider using a color mapper to shade each rect in the browser based on some other data column.